# Функции deflate и deflatePending из zlib

Tags: c, алгоритм, компрессия

Если запускать deflate с параметром Z_BLOCK, то последующий вызов deflatePending вернет в указателе количество бит, которые не были записаны в выходные данные, поскольку входных данных не хватило, чтобы сформировать на выходе полный байт. Если после этого добавить следующий блок входных данных, то вышеупомянутые биты будут записаны. У меня вопрос: с какой стороны в байт они запишутся? От младшего бита к старшему или от старшего к младшему? Смутила ссылка из статьи про deflate в Википедии. По ссылке поясняется на пальцах, как разбирается последовательность deflate, и в частности там написано, что

> все, что закодировано кодами Хаффмана идет старшим битом вперед или справа на лево.  Все остальное идет младшим битом вперед. т.е. старший бит слева.

Вот ссылка: http://compression.ru/download/articles/lz/mihalchik_deflate_decoding.html

Comment: Прошу прощения, адекватные теги вопросу невозможно добавить с репутацией ниже 300.

Comment: Исходники же есть, по ним всё посмотреть можно. Или даже собрать со своим отладочным выводом.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло. Оказалось, что в zlib огромнейшие комментарии, по крайней мере на то, что есть в zlib.h.